# LTSP overlays for fat-clients

Tags: ltsp, persistence

I've been using LTSP5.2 under Ubuntu for a while, mostly with mythbuntu. When I used to create a client image with the mythbuntu switches it created an overlay to store data for each client persistently over reboots. I could store any files in there I wanted specifically for that client.

Now that the mythbuntu switches are broken I'm going to use fat-client instead as they are maintained and work. However this does not create an overlay section.

Do I require an overlay section anymore?

Can I create one anyway? I found it good for putting settings in there per client.

Should I be using lts.conf instead?

Reference to the overlay which was in Mythbuntu 804: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MythTV/Install/Hardy/Diskless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running a similar setup to yours, my solution was to place a script in `/etc/init.d` that configures each machine at boot. There is probably a better way to do this via `lts.conf`, but this works for my setup.

**Steps**

- Create different variations of configuration files (lirc, xorg, etc.) for each client
- Store these different config files in the ltsp image with different names (`lircd.conf.machine1`, `lircd.conf.machine2`, etc.)
- Create script that runs at boot, and copies appropriate config files to appropriate locations based on hostname
- Run `update-rc.d <script_name> defaults` so the config script runs at boot

Here's the script I use, feel free to customize to meet your needs (hostnames redacted, suggestions for improvement are always welcome). Note that machine specific `xorg.conf` files aren't stored in the image, it is just created at every boot using `nvidia-xconfig`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script performs configuration of hardware
# specific components for HTPC frontends.
# log output to temp directory
exec > /tmp/htpc_config.log


# LIRC hardware and configuration
# files in place of defaults based on hostname. Required
# to automatically configure LIRC on machines with
# different hardware.
htpc_*****_suffix=".br"
htpc_*****_suffix=".lr"
lirc_hw_conf="/etc/lirc/hardware.conf"
lirc_conf="/etc/lirc/lircd.conf"

if [ "$HOSTNAME" = "*****" ]
then
    cp $lirc_hw_conf$htpc_*****_suffix $lirc_hw_conf
    cp $lirc_conf$htpc_*****_suffix $lirc_conf
    echo "Applied LIRC configuration for ***** frontend."
    service lirc restart
elif [ "$HOSTNAME" = "*****" ]
then
    cp $lirc_hw_conf$htpc_*****_suffix $lirc_hw_conf
    cp $lirc_conf$htpc_*****_suffix $lirc_conf
    echo "Applied LIRC configuration for ***** frontend."
    service lirc restart
else
    echo "Unable to match hostname $HOSTNAME."
fi

# Xorg.conf generation using nvidia-xconfig
xorgconf="/etc/X11/xorg.conf"

if [ -f "$xorgconf" ]
then
   echo "/$xorgconf exists, nothing to do."
else
   touch "$xorgconf"
   nvidia-xconfig -s
   echo "Generated $xorgconf using nvidia-xconfig."
fi
```